# How do I make it so I can access this array from any class?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, boolean

So i've been trying to get it so my array can be accessed by any class, and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Anyone know why this isn't working and what I need to change ?

```
class UnitBools {

    public static boolean[] anArray;

    public UnitBools(boolean[] anArray){
            anArray = new boolean[10];
            anArray[0] = false;
    }

    public boolean[] getArray(){
            return anArray;
    }

    public  UnitBools(){
            UnitBools.anArray[0] = true;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Element at index 0: "+ UnitBools.anArray[0]);
}
}
```

Right now my Sysout is returning a thread exception.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the exception, by any chance, a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `anArray` is an `Object`, it has a default value of `null`. You need to initialize `anArray` yourself, try:

```
public static boolean[] anArray = new boolean[1];
```

Or some other number. The number in between the `[]` represents the size of the array. From the statement above, `anArray` has a size of `1` meaning it only has `1` index, which is `0`.

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple,thought I could instantiate it in a separate method. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the static `anArray`; perhaps like so

```
private static boolean[] anArray;
static {
  final int size = 10;
  anArray = new boolean[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    anArray[i] = true;
  }
}

public static boolean[] getArray() {
  return anArray;
}
```

Which then outputs

```
true
```

with your existing `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize any static variables outside of your constructor, because they can be accessed without ever needing an instance of that class.

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + UnitBools.anArray[0]);
    }
}

class UnitBools
{
    public static boolean[] anArray = {true, true};

    public UnitBools()
    {
        //UnitBools.anArray[0] = true;
    }

    public UnitBools(boolean[] anArray)
    {
        //anArray = new boolean[10];
        //anArray[0] = false;
    }

    public boolean[] getArray()
    {
        return anArray;
    }
}
```